# How to import components using webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, module

I'm using a gulpfile with gulp-webpack - I want to split my javascript code into different modules, and have them bundled into a single minified file.

Below are the snippets of what I have for code:

function.js:

```
var $ = require('jquery');

function init() {
  console.log("piped");
  // main expansion element
  $(".button").click(function() {
    // code goes here, etc
  });
}

module.exports = init;
```

script.js

```
import script from './app/js/function.js';

module.exports = script;
```

webpack-config.js

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./app/js/script.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "public/javascripts",
    filename: "scripts.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

Gulptask:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src('app/js/script.js')
    .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/javascripts'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

This where I'm lost - my task is successfully outputting a `scripts.min.js` file to the correct directory but I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Am I not importing the import correctly? I'm refering to this documentation https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/ which is suggesting to simply use the import statement and pointing it to the file that you're referencing.

**EDIT: Dusting off my webpack knowledge, so:**

I changed:

```
import function from './app/js/function.js';

module.exports = script;
```

To:

```
var function = require('function.js');

module.exports = function;
```

But my console is now saying:

```
ERROR in ./app/js/script.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'script.js' in /projects/new-platform-prototype/app/js
 @ ./app/js/script.js 1:10-27
```

Even though the script is there?

Comment: `require('function.js')` assumes that the file is located inside the modules directory (node_modules). To reference a local file, the easiest way is to write `require('./function.js')` (watch the ./)

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading what you have here correctly, the `script.js` appears to be attempting to import itself.  You want to import, I assume the `function.js`, `import {init} from "./function"`.  Sorry I do not know your paths.  You also are not executing any code so with `script.js` you need to run it `init()`.

module.js

```
export function doesStuff() {}
```

script.js

```
import {doesStuff} from "module"

doesStuff();
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./app/js/script.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /.js?$/,
      loader: "babel-loader"
    }]
  },
 output: {
   path: __dirname + "public/javascripts",
   filename: "scripts.min.js"
 },
 ...
};
```

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. So in my main file (script.js) where I attempt to import function that first line that needs to be in `init()`?

Comment: As stated in the other answer you need to use something to transpile your ES6+ code to ES5 (like babel-loader).  Once the function is imported into your `script.js` you can run it anywhere like any other function.

Comment: Also you cannot call something `function` it is a JavaScript reserved keyword.

Comment: right I just used that as a placeholder for the name of my module.

Comment: I'm working on your version and it's still not working for me - I'm still getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Comment: In module.js I need to add `module.exports = init();` at the end right?

Comment: I think, you basically only forgot to create a `.babelrc` to that babel knows, how to transpile your code. Look at my answer above for a full sample.

Answer (score 1):

`import` statements are not officially supported yet so you have to use a plugin to transpile your code to currently supported standart.

Check out [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) for install and usage instructions.

By the way there is another bundler called [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) which supports `import`s out of the box.

**Edit:**

Just decided to put a simple rollup example here since I am big fan of it and it seems you don't know yet which bundler you're going to stick with. :)

Run `npm i -g rollup` and `rollup -c` to compile it.

**answer.js**

```
export default 42;
```

**util.js**

```
export function print(...args) {
  console.log(...args);
}
```

**index.js**

```
import answer from './answer';
import { print } from './util';

print('The answer is:', answer);
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
export default {
  input: 'index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'iife'
  }
};
```

Comment: I was having more issues with rollup than with webpack. I'm going to update my question shortly.

Comment: Thank you! I will mess around with this and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `import` you need the babel transpiler and the respective loader for your webpack config.

This is what you need to do:

**1. Setup Babel**

`npm i -D babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-es2015`

babel-core is needed to transpile your code to ECMAScript 5, so your browser can
understand it. babel-loader is used for webpack and the babel-preset-es2015 is
telling babel, how to transpile your code.

Next create a file called `.babelrc` in your projects root, containing this code:

`{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}`

**2. Configure webpack**

Finally, add this bit of code to your existing webpack config:

`module: {
  rules: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    use: 'babel-loader'
  }]
}`

**One more thing**

To unlock more ECMAScript features, check out the presets and plugins that babel offers and integrate them into your `.babelrc`.
You can find them [here](https://babeljs.io).

This answer assumes that you are using webpack in at least version 2.

**EDIT**

If you use

```
import {...} from './dir/file';
```

to import your code and omit the file extension, you need to tell webpack how to resolve this, by adding

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js']
}
```

to your webpack config.

This will tell webpack to look for `./dir/file.js` instead of just for `./dir/file`.

Comment: Yes, I did not have a `.babel.rc` in my project so that would cause issues. Despite all of this, I'm now getting `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./app/js/modules/function in /projects/project-root/app/js`

Comment: This seems to be a problem with module resolution. I edited my post. Please check the edit and let me know, if it helps.