# Webpack - module not found even though module exists

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, babeljs

[This is a branch off of my previous question and applied suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46836804/how-to-import-components-using-webpack). But I am still having major issues.

I now have my babel transpiler, along with a `.babelrc` file in place. My import code to import my module looks like this:

```
var init = require('./app/js/modules/toc');
init();
```

However I'm getting this:

```
ERROR in ./app/js/script.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./app/js/modules/toc in /projects/project-root/app/js
 @ ./app/js/script.js 1:11-42
```

Webpack config:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./app/js/script.js",
  module: {
  rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: 'babel-loader'
    }]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "public/javascripts",
    filename: "scripts.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Gulptask

```
//scripts task, also "Uglifies" JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src('app/js/script.js')
    .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/javascripts'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

I'm totally lost...what am I doing wrong?

For my import code I also tried:

```
import {toc} from './modules/toc'
toc();
```

UPDATE: As recommended I needed to add resolve to my config. It looks like this now:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./app/js/script.js",
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js']
  },
  module: {
  rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: 'babel-loader'
    }]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "public/javascripts",
    filename: "scripts.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

Sadly I still get:

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or
>   'directory' ./app/js/script.js in /projects/project-root

Does my file structure need to change?

Comment: You still haven't tried my rollup example, have you? :) Sorry for bothering you with another bundler but it is just way simpler than all the stuff you are trying to get working right now.

Comment: I have not but I'm about too. Webpack is getting completely ridiculous. I'll let you know how it goes! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying an entry point in your webpack config AND in gulp. Remove the `entry` property in your webpack config.

If you specify it twice, the gulp config will tell webpack to get the file in `./app/js/script.js`and then webpack in `./app/js/script.js` which will result in a path like `./app/js/app/js/script.js`.

Keep us posted if you fixed it. =)

Comment: Still a no go: `ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /projects/project-root/app/js/script.js in /projects/project-root` this is making me think it's a directory and not a file?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your filetree from a text editor for example ? It will help visualize files and pinpoint the issue.

Comment: gulptask was the root of the issue! I also needed to change my root property within resolve in webpack config.

Answer (score 11):

Whenever you import/require a module without specifying a file extension, you need to tell webpack how to resolve it. This is done by the `resolve` section inside the webpack config.

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js'] // add your other extensions here
}
```

As a rule of thumb: whenever webpack complains about not resolving a module, the answer probably lies in the `resolve` config.

Let me know about any further questions and if this works.

**EDIT**

`resolve` directly to the root level of your config:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.export = {
  entry: '...',
  // ...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js']
  }
  // ...
};
```

Comment: I've since included that in my config but still getting the error...will update my answer with what my config looks like.

Comment: where specifically does `resolve` go within my config? Or does it not matter?

Comment: Even with `resolve` config and using `./modules/toc` it is STILL saying it's not found.

Comment: Ok actually it my webpack config entry point that's messed up. I need to get the path right for that

Answer (score 0):

Given that your script is located at `./app/js/script.js` and the requested module is there `./app/js/modules/toc`, you would need to call it relatively to your script => `./modules/toc` should work.

This is because both your script and module are located in the `js`folder.

Comment: I tried that and i'm still getting a resolve error...is my syntax incorrect? I tried also `import {toc} from './modules/toc'
toc();`